# How to transform high row dimensionality into column dimensionality?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a 8k rows dataset that has some 50 columns. Currently a dataset like this

| ID | Name | Meeting Number | Meeting Date | Meeting Decision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John |  | null | null |
| 2 | Mike | 1 | 01-01-2020 | Waiting |
| 2 | Mike | 2 | 20-01-2020 | Approved |
| 3 | Tess | 1 | 17-01-2020 | Declined |

What I want to have

| ID | Name | Date_meeting_1 | Decision_meeting_1 | Date_meeting_2 | Decision_meeting_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | null | null | null | null |
| 2 | Mike | 01-01-2020 | Waiting | 20-01-2020 | Approved |
| 3 | Tess | 17-01-2020 | Declined | null | null |

I'm doing this in last version of Microsoft PowerBI. Totally lost here, and already tried various pivot-unpivot options without success

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in M/Powerquery.  There is extra code to preserve all-null rows which otherwise would be lost, and code to transform to date type based on column name after pivot

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content], //might need Excel.WorkBook instead for PowerBI
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,null,"[[]]",Replacer.ReplaceValue,List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(Source),{"ID","Name","Meeting Number"})),  //preserve nulls on unpivot
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value",null,1,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Meeting Number"}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Replaced Value1", {"ID", "Name","Meeting Number"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Custom", each [Attribute]&"-"&Text.From([Meeting Number])),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Meeting Number", "Attribute"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns1", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns1"[Custom]), "Custom", "Value"),
#"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Pivoted Column","[[]]",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames( #"Pivoted Column"),{"ID","Name","Meeting Number"})), //undo null preservation
#"ChangeDateType" = Table.TransformColumnTypes( #"Replaced Value2",List.Transform(List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(#"Replaced Value2"), each Text.Contains(_, "Date")),each {_, type date})) // change format to date based on column title
in   #"ChangeDateType"
```

[image]